# How to render html from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a widget that can be integrated by the third party with ease. What I need is to create a `.js` file and the user only needs to include that `javascript` file using `<script>` tags and the html tags gets rendered there.

ie.

example.com

```
widget.js

$(document).ready(function(){
    render();
    function render(){
        return '<div>Html contents to be loaded</div>';
    }
});
```

Third party file

```
thirdparty.html

<script src="http://example.com/widget.js"></script>
```

So while loading example.html how can I load all the html contents.

Comment: thirdparty.html may not of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append("<div>HTML here</div>");
});
```

Update:  As there is no body tag, you could use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("script").last().after("<div>HTML here</div>");
});
```

Remember to use `.last()` in case there is multiple script tags.